# How to access members of child class by using reference of parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

Let there are classes:

```
class Parent {
     public Parent getParent() {
         ...
     }
}

class Child extends Parent{
     public Parent getChild() {
         ...
     }
}

//instantiating Child by using reference of Parent
Parent parent = new Child();
```

when I use:

```
//Works fine
Parent parentObject = parent.getParent();
```

When I use:

```
//Doesn't works
Child childObject = parent.getChild();
```

But when type cast object:

```
//Works fine
Child childObejct = ((Child)parent).getChild();
```

being as programmer this is something hectic to type cast explicitly for  every call where I wanted to use child members by reference of parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so complicated. When you have an up-cast, it is simple for the compiler to determine the real type and do the cast because you know every class is simply extended from one parent.

But when you are down-casting an object, compiler can not infer that an object with a Parent reference is which Child object in the runtime because every Parent class can have multiple Child class.

Good Luck.

Comment: I got your point but catch here is every time I need to write code to cast object, consider if there are 20 members then I have to use casting 20 times.

Comment: No don't have to. simply create reference of Child ch = (Child)parent; after that use only the ch reference which has all the parent and child refences.

Answer (score 2):

You declared a variable of type `Parent` named `parent` that is actually a `Child`.

If you don't cast the variable you can use only the methods of class `Parent`.

If you cast the variable to the real type (that in this case is `Child`) you can access to all the methods of class `Child` and its super class `Parent` too.

**Note:** to have less misunderstandings it is better to name the variable `child` also if you assign it to the type `Parent`, so it is clear that this is a real Child.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this? I did not understand what you want...

```
    abstract class Parent {
     public Parent(){
     }
     public abstract void doStuff();

}

 class Child extends Parent{
     public Child() {
     super();
     }

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

In the main do this

```
Child c = new Child();
c.doStuff();
```

Comment: I want to use parent class reference to store child object but wanted to know is there any way by which I can get ridd off casting it every time by Child type. Casting once in code, its fine for me but this also doesn't works for me.

Comment: This works, but this would leads to overriding not overloading, right?

Comment: Yes, read this if you're confused http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/difference-between-method-overloading-and-overriding-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

```
//Doesn't works
// parent.getChild() returning Parent object and you are trying to assign to child object, which is not possible implicitly.
Child childObject = parent.getChild();
```

You can try some more cases by changing as below too:

```
class Parent {
    public Parent getParent() {
        return new Parent();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public Child getChild() {
        return new Child();
    }

    // to access methods of child class using Parent class,
    //You should Override(same method Names and signatures) the methods of Parent Class
    public Parent getParent() {
        return new Parent();
    }
}
```